# Clang Tool that extracts the lambda body given the lambda type

Tags: c++, clang

I'm currently trying to implement a Clang Tool based on RecursiveASTVisitors (based on [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) tutorial) that applies code transformations based on lambdas given to a function.

E.g. generate something based on the lambda given as an argument to `foo`:

```
foo([](){});
```

This is easily possible. Find all `callExpr`s that have the name `foo` and then find all `lambdaExpr`s that are descendants of this `callExpr`:

```
struct LambdaExprVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<LambdaExprVisitor> {
  bool VisitLambdaExpr(LambdaExpr * lambdaExpr) {
    //Do stuff
    lambdaExpr->getCallOperator()->getBody()->dump();
    return true;
  }
};

struct CallVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<CallVisitor> {
  //Find call expressions based on the given name
  bool VisitCallExpr(CallExpr * expr) {
    auto * callee = expr->getDirectCallee(); 
    if(callee != nullptr && callee->getName() == "foo") {
      visitor.TraverseCallExpr(expr);
    }
    return true;
  }
  LambdaExprVisitor visitor;
};
```

The problem that I now have is that there are multiple ways to get to pass a lambda function to this original function `foo`, e.g.:

```
auto bar() { return [](){}; }

int main() {
  foo(bar());
}
```

And the earlier approach to get the body does not work here.

Now I thought that the lambdas' bodies are known during compile-time and therefore the lambda body must somehow be inferable given the value of the `Expr` of the given paramter:

```
struct CallVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<CallVisitor> {
  bool VisitCallExpr(CallExpr * expr) {
    auto * callee = expr->getDirectCallee(); 
    if(callee != nullptr && callee->getName() == "foo") {
      //Get the first argument which must be the lambda
      auto * arg = expr->getArg(0);
      //do something with the the first argument
      //?
    };
    return true;
  }
};
```

Is there a way to get the lambda body at this point?
If not, is there a way to infer the lambda body differently without having to resort to implementing all possible ways to pass a lambda body to `foo`?

Note: A matcher-based solution would also work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to first traverse the translation unit and gather all `lambdaExpr`s in a map that has their type as keys. Then, in a second traversal of the translation unit, it is possible to infer the lambda's body by the type. 
Here are the modified Visitors that now store a reference to this map (The type is encoded as its string representation):

```
struct LambdaExprVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<LambdaExprVisitor> {
  LambdaExprVisitor(std::map<std::string, LambdaExpr *>& id2Expr) : RecursiveASTVisitor<LambdaExprVisitor> {}, id2Expr { id2Expr } {} 

  std::map<std::string, LambdaExpr *>& id2Expr; 

  bool VisitLambdaExpr(LambdaExpr * lambdaExpr) {
    id2Expr.emplace(
      lambdaExpr->getType().getAsString(),
      lambdaExpr
    );
    return true;
  }
};

struct CallVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<CallVisitor> {
  CallVisitor(std::map<std::string, LambdaExpr *>& id2Expr) : RecursiveASTVisitor<CallVisitor> {}, id2Expr { id2Expr } {} 

  std::map<std::string, LambdaExpr *>& id2Expr;

  bool VisitCallExpr(CallExpr * expr) {
    auto * callee = expr->getDirectCallee(); 
    if(callee != nullptr && callee->getName() == "foo") {
      //Get the expr from the map
      auto arg = expr->getArg(0)->getType().getAsString();
      if(auto iter = id2Expr.find(arg); iter != id2Expr.end()) {
        //Do stuff with the lambdaExpr
        auto * lambdaExpr = iter->second;
        lambdaExpr->dump();
      }
    };
    return true;
  }
};
```

The `ASTConsumer` to handle this just stores this map and executes the two visitors:

```
struct Consumer : public ASTConsumer {
    public: 

    virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext &Context) override {
      visitor.TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
      visitor2.TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
    }

    std::map<std::string, LambdaExpr *> id2Expr; 

    LambdaExprVisitor visitor { id2Expr };
    CallVisitor visitor2 { id2Expr };

  };
```